# ROS2 using python project in node

Tags: python, ros2

I have written a ros2 python service node. In this node I want to use functionalities from another python project so I can run inference using a pretrained model with the node. I have cloned the git repository into my /ros2_ws under source.
This is my node:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from inference_interfaces.srv import Inference

#SPIGA INCLDUES:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from SPIGA.spiga.inference.config import ModelConfig
from SPIGA.spiga.inference.framework import SPIGAFramework
import copy

class Inference_Service(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('inference_service')
        self.srv = self.create_service(Inference, 'inference', self.inference_callback)
        #instatiating processor:
        dataset = 'wflw'
        self.processor = SPIGAFramework(ModelConfig(dataset, load_model_url=False))

    def inference_callback(self, request, response):
        features = self.processor.inference(request.image, request.bbox)
        # Prepare variables
        response.landmarks = np.array(features['landmarks'][0])
        response.headpose = np.array(features['headpose'][0])
        return response
    

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    inference = Inference_Service()

    rclpy.spin(inference)

    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The layout of my /ros2_ws looks like the following:

-ros2_ws

--src

---py_inference_service

---cpp_inference_client

---inference_interfaces

---SPIGA

Im working in the py_inference_service package and I want to include modules from my SPIGA repository. When I do this using the "from SPIGA.spiga.inference.config import ModelConfig" it builds using colcon but when i try to run the code it tells me:

File "/home/victor/ros2_ws/install/py_inference_service/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py_inference_service/service_memberfunction.py", line 9, in

```
from SPIGA.spiga.inference.config import ModelConfig
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SPIGA'

In my package.xml I have linked SPIGA as a dependency. Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i was faceing was standard python filepath issues.
Because I was working in my ros workspace the root folder wherent where I thought.
I solved the issue using a workaround tho where I used pip to install my source file as a local library.